# Ambari, connection failed on datanode

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I have done an installation of Ambari with Hadoop on my cluster.
I'm behind a proxy, and I have no problem during the installation...
When I start all service on Ambari, I have this errors :

HDFS    DataNode Process -> Connection failed: [Errno 111] Connection refused to 0.0.0.0:50010
HDFS    DataNode Web UI ->  Connection failed to http://testslave3.ingc.com:50075

I tried many possibilities, but I don’t know where is the problem…

If you have any suggestion… thanks a lot :)

Comment: hello, have you figured out the problems? I am getting the same one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using MySQL as the DB repository?  If so, after upgrading to the latest mysql-connector-java, and registering this to the ambari-server, I no longer had this issue:

1. Get the mysql-connector-java RPM:

   - wget ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/x86_64/os/Packages/m/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-1.fc23.noarch.rpm
2. Install the RPM:

   - rpm -ivh mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-1.fc23.noarch.rpm
3. Confirm that .jar is in the Java share directory

   - ls /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar
4. Modify ambari-server to use this connector:

   - ambari-server setup --jdbc-db=mysql --jdbc-driver=/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar